# Long tap on votes results in empty space in case question has no votes

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

When a user has 1000+ rep on a site it is possible to view vote statistics in the iOS app by long pressing on the voting area of a post.

However in case the question has no votes at all an empty space is presented which is really confusing:

> [image]

Maybe `+0/-0` should be displayed or the functionality should just not be provided in said case.

Note: In case the question has a score of 0 by 3 upvotes and 3 downvotes the functionality works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've updated the UI to follow what the site does in this case: simply show a +0 and -0.

[image]

This will be updated in beta version 1.2.0.137.

Comment: Yeah, I wondered about the version... :)

Comment: Yup, I've updated the version to the correct one.